# Unity + Xcode iOS Build - Missing symbols for

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, apple-push-notifications

Fighting this issue for a couple of days now and finally have to give in and ask for help. 
Im Building A Unity Game that is exported to Xcode. Instead of direct export using Objective C, the game is converted into a Swift 4.0 project.
[Check Here for more info on how its done](https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82).
I have a build multiple apps this way and have not faced this issue as of yet but none of the previous apps had push notifications.

Few things worth mentioning:

- The game works when directly exported from Unity to Xcode.
- The app does not build with error mentioned below.
- The app crashes when it is supposed to ask for notification permission.(when code commented out see below)

So I managed to pinpoint where the error is starting and its related to this class LocalNotificationAppController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/NSURLConnection.h>
#import <Foundation/NSURL.h>

#import "UnityAppController.h"

extern bool _unityAppReady;

@interface LocalNotificationAppController : UnityAppController
{}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler;
@end

@implementation LocalNotificationAppController
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    [self notifyUnityOfAction:identifier inNotification:notification completionHandler:completionHandler];
}


- (void)notifyUnityOfAction:(NSString*)identifier inNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    if (_unityAppReady)
    {
        NSArray *parts = [identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        if (parts.count == 3) {
            NSString *gameObject = parts[0];
            NSString *handlerMethod = parts[1];
            NSString *action = parts[2];
            UnitySendMessage(strdup([gameObject UTF8String]), strdup([handlerMethod UTF8String]), strdup([action UTF8String]));
            UnityBatchPlayerLoop();
        }

        if (completionHandler != nil)
            completionHandler();
    }
    else
    {
        NSNotificationCenter * __weak center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        id __block token = [center addObserverForName:@"UnityReady" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
            _unityAppReady = true;
            [center removeObserver:token];
            [self notifyUnityOfAction:identifier inNotification:notification completionHandler:completionHandler];
        }];
    }
}
@end

//IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(LocalNotificationAppController)
```

which links to

```
#define IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(ClassName) \
@interface ClassName(OverrideAppDelegate)       \
{                                               \
}                                               \
+(void)load;                                    \
@end                                            \
@implementation ClassName(OverrideAppDelegate)  \
+(void)load                                     \
{                                               \
    extern const char* AppControllerClassName;  \
    AppControllerClassName = #ClassName;        \
}                                               \
@end
```

inside UnityAppController.h

So the build fails with following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_AppControllerClassName", referenced from:
>         +[LocalNotificationAppController(OverrideAppDelegate) load] in LocalNotificationAppController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

and if comment out this line in LocalNotificationAppController:

```
//IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(LocalNotificationAppController)
```

The build works but there is a thread exception occurring exactly where the app should ask for permission.

Comment: May I know why you convert your project from objc to swift?

Comment: Sure. 1 - requirements for the project. 2 - the unity part is only a small portion of the whole application.3 - objective C is using quite old frameworks and new ones are not available. For example no wkwebview support.